# Not able to upload base64 image to S3 AWS in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload a base64 image to s3 bucket.But I am getting error

> Error in upload TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "chunk" argument
> must be of type string or an instance of Buffer. Received an instance
> of Buffer

Below is my code --

```
     const image='/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEASABIAAD/4gxYSUNDX1BST0ZJTEUAAQEAAAxITGl..........'
        const buf = Buffer.from(image.replace(/^data:image\/\w+;base64,/, ""),'base64')

    // Setting up S3 upload parameters
    const params = {
        Bucket: this.s3bucketpath,
        Key:'abcd.jpg', // File name you want to save as in S3
        Body: buf,
        ContentEncoding: 'base64', 
    ContentType: 'image/jpg' 
    };
    
  const result=  await this.s3.upload(params).promise();
```

AWS SDK version - 2.952.0

Comment: Don't know for sure but I do the same thing in my code and the only difference I can see is the 'new' before buffer, so the code would look like const buf = new Buffer.from(image.replace(/^data:image\/\w+;base64,/, ""),'base64')

Comment: I have tried by that also not working. Also new Buffer(str) is deprecated. @proxim0.

Comment: what happens if you do `buf.toString()`? Just curious in that scenario, in my code i use buffers most of the time, and sometimes a string depending on the use case.

Comment: @tam.teixeira It is showing error that image cannot be displayed because it contains error.